# Parsing text and JSON from a log file and keeping them together

Tags: python, json

I have a .log file containing both text strings and json. For example:

```
A whole bunch of irrelevant text
2022-12-15 12:45:06, run: 1, user: james json:
[{"value": "30", "error": "8"}]
2022-12-15 12:47:36, run: 2, user: kelly json:
[{"value": "15", "error": "3"}]
More irrelevant text
```

My goal is to extract the json but keep it paired with the text that comes before it so that the two can be tied together. The keyword that indicates the start of a new section is `run`. However, as shown in the example below, I need to extract the timestamp from the same line where `run` appears. The character that indicates the end of a section is `]`.

My goal is to parse this text into a pandas dataframe like the following:

```
timestamp              run   user     value    error
2022-12-15 12:45:06    1     james    30       5
2022-12-15 12:47:36    2     kelly    15       8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

pat = re.compile(
    r"(?ms)^([^,\n]+),\s*run:\s*(\S+),\s*user:\s*(.*?)\s*json:\n(.*?)$"
)

all_data = []
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for timestamp, run, user, json_line in pat.findall(f_in.read()):
        json_line = json.loads(json_line)
        all_data.append(
            {
                "timestamp": timestamp,
                "run": run,
                "user": user,
                "value": json_line[0]["value"],
                "error": json_line[0]["error"],
            }
        )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
             timestamp run   user  value  error
0  2022-12-15 12:45:06   1  james     30      5
1  2022-12-15 12:47:36   2  kelly     15      8
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej. Was able to get this to work. Just a heads up, there is an extra comma here `"error": json_line[0]["error"],`

Comment: Those extra commas are permissible in Python, and are actually considered good style. It makes it easy to change the code in the future to add more key-values to a dict, or to rearrange the lines in a dict.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the json data and the timestamp from the text file, you can use Regex to search for the expression that indicates the start of a new section. In this case, the pattern you're looking for is the time followed by the keyword "run". In Python this would look like:

```
with open("file.log", "r") as f:
    text = f.read()

matches = re.findall(r"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}), run: \d+, user: \w+ json:", text)

data = []

for match in matches:
    timestamp, run, user, value, error = re.search(r"^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}), run: (\d+), user: (\w+) json: \[{"value": (\d+), "error": (\d+)}]$", match).groups()
    data.append((timestamp, int(run), user, int(value), int(error)))

# Tuples => DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["timestamp", "run", "user", "value", "error"])
```

`

Comment: Thank you so much. When I try to run that I'm getting an error: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?` This is occurring for the loop of match in matches

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes people find regular expressions hard to follow or maintain, so I wrote pyparsing to make code that parses this kind of data easier to read. (This code uses the jsonValue parser from the [jsonParser.py example in the pyparsing examples directory](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/jsonParser.py).) This may also be easier to modify in the future, if your data format changes.

```
sample = """\
uninteresting text
2022-12-15 12:45:06, run: 1, user: james json:
[{"value": "30", "error": "8"}]
2022-12-15 12:47:36, run: 2, user: kelly json:
[{"value": "15", "error": "3"}]
uninteresting text
"""

import pyparsing as pp
from .jsonParser import jsonValue

timestamp = pp.common.iso8601_datetime()
integer = pp.common.integer()
user = pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums + "_")
COMMA = pp.Suppress(",")

record = (timestamp("timestamp") + COMMA
          + "run:" + integer("run") + COMMA
          + "user:" + user("user")
          + "json:" + jsonValue("data"))

def annotate_record(tokens):
    return {
        "timestamp": tokens.timestamp,
        "run": tokens.run,
        "user": tokens.user,
        "value": tokens.data[0]["value"],
        "error": tokens.data[0]["error"]
    }
record.add_parse_action(annotate_record)

for match in record.search_string(sample):
    print(match.dump())
```

Prints:

```
[{'timestamp': '2022-12-15 12:45:06', 'run': 1, 'user': 'james', 'value': '30', 'error': '8'}]
[{'timestamp': '2022-12-15 12:47:36', 'run': 2, 'user': 'kelly', 'value': '15', 'error': '3'}]
```

If you just want a pretty tabular output, [littletable](https://pypi.org/project/littletable/) is much lighter weight than pandas (and can also do other simple tabular functions, such as CSV import/export):

```
import littletable as lt
data_table = lt.Table().insert_many(rec[0] for rec in record.search_string(sample))
data_table.present()
```

littletable uses the rich package for table presentation.

```
  Timestamp             Run   User    Value   Error 
 ───────────────────────────────────────────────────
  2022-12-15 12:45:06     1   james   30        8
  2022-12-15 12:47:36     2   kelly   15        3
```