# Parsing a log file and ignoring text between two targets

Tags: python, regex

This question is a follow-up to my previous question here: [Parsing text and JSON from a log file and keeping them together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74818311/9394364)

I have a log file, `your_file.txt` with the following structure and I would like to extract the timestamp, run, user, and json:

```
A whole bunch of irrelevant text
2022-12-15 12:45:06 garbage, run: 1, user: james json:
[{"value": 30, "error": 8}]
```

Another stack user was helpful enough to provide this abridged code to extract the relevant pieces:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(
    r'(?ms)^([^,\n]+),\s*run:\s*(\S+),\s*user:\s*(.*?)\s*json:\n(.*?)$'
)

with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    print(pat.findall(f_in.read()))
```

Which returns this value which is then processed further:

```
[('2022-12-15 12:45:06 garbage', '1', 'james', '[{"value": 30, "error": 8}]')]
```

How can I amend the regex expression used to ignore the word "garbage" after the timestamp so that word is not included in the output of `pat.findall`?

Comment: Does the "whole bunch of irrelevant text" happen to end in some data that isn't all that irrelevant, like: "timestamp:", "date:" or something similar? Also, even if it doesn't it still might not be irrelevant, because it might reveal a constant formatting that can be used to get this stuff in a more fuzzy way.

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately not, it always varies. There's nothing consistent there. The main extract logic works great, so no issues identifying the start of a section, main thing is just figuring out how to drop text between the end of the timestamp and `run`

Comment: hacky: `' '.join(timestamp.split(' ')[:2])`

Comment: Something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/ArxOK1/1) could suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the date time pattern to match date time first and then the rest of the substring before `,`:

```
(?ms)^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})[^,\n]*,\s*run:\s*(\S+),\s*user:\s*(.*?)\s*json:\n(.*?)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FJg8fM/2).

The `([^,\n]+)` is replaced with `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})[^,\n]*` that matches

- `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})` - Group 1: four digits, two occurrences of `-` and then two digits, a space, two digits, and then two occurrences of `:` and then two digits
- `[^,\n]*` - zero or more chars other than a comma and newline